# Design SQL tables with a list behaviour

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have one table

```
Client (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY );
```

Another table;

```
Exercise (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY );
```

And a final table;

```
Workout (
  name VARCHAR,
  creator INT REFERENCES Client(id),
  exercise INT REFERENCES Exercise(id),
  PRIMARY KEY(name,creator,exercise) );
```

My tables has some other columns aswell but these are all the relevant ones.
A workout has a creator, it is given a name (for example 'legs - monday' or whatever) and then it has a list of unique exercises one is to perform during this workout. So in an Object oriented approach this would look something like

```
Object Workout
  string name
  int creator
  List<Exercise> exercises
```

So far this has worked well for me but now i need to create a new table that has a reference to a workout, and i am not sure how to capture this. Maybe my implementation of this is wrong?

```
table A (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  workout References Workout(?) );
```

I cannot reference (name,creator) since it is not marked as unique, and even if it was i would only be able to add one exercise then. It seems silly to reference all rows in Workout (my teacher in relational databases would skin me alive).

Would it be bad practice to just reference one arbitrary entry to a workout (name,creator,exercise)? If i have the name and the creator i can just make a select statement and get all the exercises from them. All rows where the tuple (name,creator) match are said to belong to the same workout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children should reference a parent, not vice versa:

```
create table client (
    id serial primary key
);

create table workout (
    id serial primary key,
    name varchar,
    creator int references client(id)
);

create table exercise (
    id serial primary key,
    workout int references workout(id)
);
```

Then your *list view* for a given workout may look like this:

```
select *
from workout w
left join exercise e on e.workout = w.id
where name = 'some name';
```

---

Edit. In case of many-to-many relationship the common way is to create so-called *join table*, e.g.:

```
create table workout_parts (
    workout int references workout(id),
    exercise int references exercise(id),
    primary key (workout, exercise)
);
```

Comment: Sorry maybe i was a little quick while writing my thread. An exercise does not necessarily have to be a part of a workout. A user is supposed to be able to create some exercises, and if he/she wishes, just group a few together as a workout. The same exercise is supposed to be able to be a part of several different workouts, aswell.

Comment: Maybe a simple Exercise table, a Workout table and a third table ExercisesInWorkout ( Workout REFERENCES Workout(id), Exercise REFERENCES Exercise(id)); would get the trick done.

Comment: I see. Still it is strange to have several rows for one object in the table `workout`. See the edited answer.

Comment: Just saw your edit, you posted it about a second after i made this comment. I thought about it for a while and it would probably work. I feel stupid now for not considering this from the beginning.